# jquery menu (some `<li>` contains inner `<ul>` tags)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

i have created a dynamic side category menu.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(' #cate_id2 > ul > #subcate_id4 > ul').hide();

            $(' #cate_id2 > ul > #subcate_id4 ').hover(function () {
                $(' #cate_id2 > ul > #subcate_id4 > ul').stop().slideDown('fast');
            },

           function () {
               $(' #cate_id2 > ul > #subcate_id4 > ul').stop().slideUp('fast');
           });
        });
```

But here some `<li>` contains inner  tags, so i want it will works as    - all `<li>` should work without giving the id of individual `<li`> tag (it contains), i mean that if any `<li>` tag contains inner `<ul>` to show, than it should work on hover

**here the id of the `<li>` (contains inner ul)----  `subcate_id4`**

**i tried it as ------**

```
$(document).ready(function () { $(' #cate_id2 > ul').show(); });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(' #cate_id2 > ul > li:has(ul) > ul').hide();

            $(' #cate_id2 > ul > li:has(ul) > ul ').hover(function () {
                $(' #cate_id2 > ul > li:has(ul) > ul').stop().slideDown('fast');
            },

           function () {
               $(' #cate_id2 > ul > li:has(ul) > ul').stop().slideUp('fast');
           });
        });
```

**but didnt worked**

Comment: The problem you have is you are adding the hover events to the element that is hidden! Pretty hard to mouse over an element that is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(' #cate_id2 > ul > li > ul').hide();
$(' #cate_id2 > ul > li:has(ul)').hover(
    function () { 
        $(this).find("> ul").stop().slideDown("fast");
    },
    function () { 
        $(this).find("> ul").stop().slideUp("fast");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$('#list li').has('ul').hover(function() {
    // ...
});
</script>
```

Please, show me the HTML structure so I can complete the code. Your selectors are a nightmare! :)